# Jenkins Pipeline Get Current Stage Status After Using catchError

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is a follow-up to my earlier question:

[Set a stage status in Jenkins Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471101/set-a-stage-status-in-jenkins-pipelines/56975266#56975266)

It turns out I can keep a pipeline as SUCCESS but can mark an individual stage as UNSTABLE if I want via `catchError` like this:

```
node()
{
    stage("Stage 1")
    {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE')
        {
            sh 'exit 1'
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to get the current status of the pipeline itself, I can use `currentBuild.getCurrentResult()` but I don't see a `currentStage` analog to this.

I'm interested in trying out a pattern that might look something like this in my stages:

```
stage("1") {
    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
        // do stuff
    }
    // perhaps more catchError() blocks
    if(currentStage.getCurrentResult() == "UNSTABLE") {
        // do something special if we're unstable
    }
}
```

but that would fail because there's no `currentStage` available.

So basically, `catchError()` is nice but I'd like to know how I can catch the status change to my stage if it gets changed... Does anyone know how you access the status of the current stage you're in from a pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though there is no direct method for accessing the result of a stage in a pipeline as of now, you can work around it. This is  considering you are only interested in either `SUCCESS` or `UNSTABLE` stage results as per the question and not in `FAILURE`.

The workaround is to initialize an empty map at the top of your pipeline to store the result of each stage. Now, instead of the `catchError()` method, use the `unstable()` method in combination with a try-catch block. This is because the latter not only lets you set the result as unstable but also perform other operations such as add the result to the map in the except block. Then you can read this stored result from the map in your `if` statement.

**Example**

```
stageResults = [:]
...
stage("1") {
    try {
        // do stuff
        // Add to map as SUCCESS on successful execution 
        stageResults."{STAGE_NAME}" = "SUCCESS"
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Set the result and add to map as UNSTABLE on failure
        unstable("[ERROR]: ${STAGE_NAME} failed!")
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
        stageResult."{STAGE_NAME}" = "UNSTABLE"
    }
    if(stageResults.find{ it.key == "{STAGE_NAME}" }?.value == "UNSTABLE") {
        // do something special if we're unstable
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already do something like that but I usually just set a boolean state variable like `Boolean stageFailed = false` at the start of the `stage` block and then do try/catch stuff and check it later.  I had been hopeful that the `catchError` would simplify this a bit but it looks like it works kind of like a specialized try block with a hidden catch which sets some state that isn't accessible to the pipeline which limits its utility for us.  That changes if I can access the status of the current stage somehow... but it's looking like that's not possible at this time. :(

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this (to keep the catchError):

```
def boolean test_results = false

pipeline {
    ...
    stage( 'x' ) {
        steps{
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                
                <Do some dangerous stuff here>
                
                //
                // If we reached here the above step hasn't failed
                //
                script { test_results = true }
            }
        }
    }
    stage( 'y' ) {
        steps{
            script{
                if( test_results == true ) {
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As for me the most elegant way to do it, it's a [post](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) section.
In your example, you mark the stage as `UNSTABLE` so after that you can catch it using `post->unstable`.

```
stage("1") {
    steps {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
            error 'Something goes wrong'
        }
    }
    post {
        always { echo 'Executed on every build'}
        unstable { echo 'Executed only if build is unstable (marked by catchError)'}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer for a declarative pipeline. Sadly not for scripted pipelines.

Comment: Is this the code behind `post` (?) https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/6e94552bed1505958199f1563e6509a9f7e74f6a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/declarative/PostDeclaration.groovy#L58 if so it doesn't seem to shed any obvious light on how to fetch the current stage result (presumably 'delegate' is different when within a stage?)

Comment: This approach seems to have some issues: When removing the "always" line, the "unstable" is never executed (which seems to be a bug in Jenkins). Additionally, when wanting to keep also the buildResult 'UNSTABLE' (not like in the example 'SUCCESS'), the "unstable" section will also be executed when a previous stage already set the buildResult to 'UNSTABLE'.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to add to Dibakar Aditya's answer, it is possible to wrap everything in a function which resembles regular steps. I.e.:

```
stage("1") {
    def localSuccess = catchLocalError {
        // do stuff
    }
    if(!localSuccess) {
        // do something special if we're unstable
    }
}

boolean catchLocalError(Closure c) {
    try {
        c()
        return true
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing I like about possibly using `catchError` is that it can set the status of an individual stage to UNSTABLE, etc. and that shows up in the Stage View in Jenkins... is there a way to set the status of an individual stage without using catchError?

Comment: Should be possible to fix is you're willing to move the stage step inside of catchLocalError/catchError. If interested I can update my answer.

Comment: you can move catchError inside the catch also.  what im struggling with is from a function like the above, how do you mark the stage as failure.