# How to run pipeline irrespective of stage failure and capture errors and report the failed stages at end

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

First of all, Thanks for looking into my concern.

I have below pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage(‘one’) {
        steps {
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            bat '''
            echo “stage one”;
            exit 1;
            '''
            echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
            //echo "RESULT2 ${currentBuild.stageResult}"
        } //catch
        }//steps
    }//stage 1
        stage('RunParallel') {
            parallel { 
                stage(‘two’) {
                    steps {
                    bat '''
                    echo “stage two”;
                    exit 0;
                    '''
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                }
                
                stage(‘three’) {
                    steps {
                    bat '''
                    echo “stage three”;
                    exit 0;
                    '''
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                }
                
                stage(‘four’) {
                    steps {
                    bat '''
                    echo “stage four”;
                    exit 0;
                    '''
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                }
            }//parallel
        }//runParallel

    stage(‘validate’) {
      steps {
        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
        bat 'echo validation stage'
      }

    }
    stage(‘five’) {
      steps {
        bat '''
        echo “stag e 5”;
        exit 0;
        '''
      }
    }

  }
  post {
    always {
    bat '''
      echo ‘I will always execute this!’
      '''
    }
  }
}
```

And pipeline looks like his.
[image]

My goal is:

1. even if stage1 fails, I need to run stages 2,3,4
2. a. if stage 1,2,3,4 fails, I have to report it in validation stage and fail the build
   b. if stage 1,2,3,4 succeeds, I need to pass validation and proceed towards stage5 and later stages

Right now I am able to do first step with catch block. And, stuck at step2. Can you guide on how to capture stage result and report failed stages.

Comment: Hope this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736150/jenkins-pipeline-get-current-stage-status-after-using-catcherror

Comment: I tried several ways mentioned there, It's not helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to capture all the stage results and filter failed stages. Now I can write conditions around it. Here's what I have got.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
rstages=[:]

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage(‘one’) {
        steps {
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            bat '''
            echo “stage one”;
            exit 1;
            '''
            script{
            echo "stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
            echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
            }
        } //catch
        }//steps
        post {
                always {
                    script{
                    println "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    println "current stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
                    rstages."${env.STAGE_NAME}" = "${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                }
            } 
    }//stage 1
    
        stage('RunParallel') {
            parallel { 
                stage(‘two’) {
                    steps {
                    bat '''
                    echo “stage two”;
                    exit 0;
                    '''
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                        script{
                        println "current stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
                        rstages."${env.STAGE_NAME}" = "${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                stage(‘three’) {
                    steps {
                    bat '''
                    echo “stage three”;
                    exit 0;
                    '''
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                        script{
                        println "current stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
                        rstages."${env.STAGE_NAME}" = "${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                stage(‘four’) {
                    steps {
                    bat '''
                    echo “stage four”;
                    exit 0;
                    '''
                    echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                        script{
                        println "current stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
                        rstages."${env.STAGE_NAME}" = "${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//parallel
        }//runParallel

    stage(‘validate’) {
      steps {
        script{
        //println RESULT: "${currentBuild.result}"
        //println "stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
        println "Printing all stage results"
        rstages.each{entry -> println "$entry.key=$entry.value"}  // to print all elements in map object rstages
        }
        script{
        //help: https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-maps
        println "printing failed stages"
        def fstages=rstages.findAll{ key, value -> value.contains('FAIL') } //to print all keys matching a value FAILURE
        println fstages 
        }
      }
      post {
                        always {
                        script{
                        println "current stage name is: ${env.STAGE_NAME}"
                        rstages."${env.STAGE_NAME}" = "${currentBuild.result}"
                    }
                        }
                    }

    }
    stage(‘five’) {
      steps {
        bat '''
        echo “stage 5”;
        exit 0;
        '''
      }
    }

  }
  post {
    always {
    bat '''
      echo ‘I will always execute this!’
      '''
    }
  }
}
```