# Jenkins declarative pipeline. Stage post action goes to failure block if previous stage failed and current stage is successful

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have pipeline runs 3 stages. success, fail, success. Yes I want the pipeline continue to run even one stage fails.
This screenshot looks right.
My problem is, the last stage `green2` is successful but the post action went to `failure` block instead of `success`.
Here is output

```
green success
red failure
green2 failure
```

My goal is catch every stage status and send to slack.  With catchError(), if the stage fail I cannot assign a global variable to indicates that stage failed.
Thank you in advance for your help!
[image]

```
pipeline {
    stages {    
        stage("green"){            
            steps{
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh 'exit 0'
                }               
            }
            post{
                success {
                    echo 'green success'
                }
                failure{
                    echo 'green fail'
                }               
            }
        }       
        stage("red"){
           
            steps{
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh 'exit 1'
                }
            }
            post{
                success {
                    echo 'red success'
                }
                failure{
                    echo 'red failure'
                }           
            }
        }
        
        stage("green2"){
            steps{
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh 'exit 0'
                }
            }
            post{
                success {
                    echo 'green2 success'
                }
                failure{
                    echo 'green2 failure'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins 2.401.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation of the @m-b 's answer, accumulating stage results in a map

```
def stageResults = [:]
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("green"){
      steps{
        script { stageResults[STAGE_NAME] = 'failure' }
        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
          sh 'exit 0'
          script { stageResults[STAGE_NAME] = 'success' }
        }
      }
    }
    stage("red"){
      steps{
        script { stageResults[STAGE_NAME] = 'failure' }
        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
          sh 'exit 1'
          script { stageResults[STAGE_NAME] = 'success' }
        }
      }
    }
    stage("green2"){
      steps{
        script { stageResults[STAGE_NAME] = 'failure' }
        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
          sh 'exit 0'
          script { stageResults[STAGE_NAME] = 'success' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post{
    always {
      echo "Stage results: ${stageResults}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I can process the map in the final post section like `echo "green2 result " + stageResults.get('green2')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the status of each stage regardless of what it is, you could completely remove both `success` and `failure` post stages and replace them with an `always` block. Then, in the always block you could have an if condition where you send the correct Slack message. Drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263417/3730626), your pipeline would look like this:

```
def boolean test_results = false

...
stage("red"){
    steps{
        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh 'exit 1'
            script { test_results = true }
        }
    }
    post{
        always {
            if( test_results == true ) {
                echo 'red success'
            } else {
                echo 'red failure'
            }
            test_results = false
        }        
    }
}

stage("green2"){
    steps{
        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh 'exit 0'
            script { test_results = true }
        }
    }
    always {
        if( test_results == true ) {
            echo 'green2 success'
        } else {
            echo 'green2 failure'
        }   
        test_results = false
    }   
}
```

You can move the if condition out into a function to reduce code duplication.

Comment: Thank you!  The script works perfectly after I move the test_results to the else block however, My real script is not boolean. My test_results was set as 'SKIP' initially. I want the script set it to 'SUCCESS' or 'FAILURE'.  I have trouble to set it to FAILURE so I tried the post::failure but can't make that work.

Comment: Oh I got it.  I learned something from @Iterokun post that I put test_result as failure before running the red catchError().